# How to encode tuple to JSON in elm

Tags: json, decode, encode, elm

I have tuple of (String,Bool) that need to be encoded to JSON Array in elm.

This below link is useful for the primitive types and other list, array and object. But I need to encode tuple2.

Refer : http://package.elm-lang.org/packages/elm-lang/core/4.0.3/Json-Encode#Value

I tried different approach like encoding tuple with toString function. 
It does not gives me JSON Array instead it produces String as below `"(\"r"\,False)"`.

JSON.Decoder expecting the input paramater to decode as below snippet.

```
decodeString (tuple2 (,) float float) "[3,4]"
```

Refer : http://package.elm-lang.org/packages/elm-lang/core/4.0.3/Json-Decode

Q : When there is decode function available for tuple2, why encode function is missing it.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can build a generalized tuple size 2 encoder like this:

```elm
import Json.Encode exposing (..)

tuple2Encoder : (a -> Value) -> (b -> Value) -> (a, b) -> Value
tuple2Encoder enc1 enc2 (val1, val2) =
  list [ enc1 val1, enc2 val2 ]
```

Then you can call it like this, passing the types of encoders you want to use for each slot:

```elm
tuple2Encoder string bool ("r", False)
```

Answer (score 7):

In elm 0.19 https://package.elm-lang.org/packages/elm/json/latest/Json-Encode a generalized tuple 2 encoder would be

```
import Json.Encode exposing (list, Value)
tuple2Encoder : ( a -> Value ) -> ( b -> Value ) -> ( a, b ) -> Value
tuple2Encoder enc1 enc2 ( val1, val2 ) =
    list identity [ enc1 val1, enc2 val2 ]
```

Usage:

```
encode 0 <| tuple2Encoder string int ("1",2)
```